# C++: "vector<int>::size_type variable" - what is the point of declaring in this way?

Tags: c++, vector, types, std

I think this is a very basic question but I couldn't just figure it out.

I was used to using arrays in C++ but I'm now starting to learn vectors.
I was making a test code, and I came across a question.

First of all, here's the code I made:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <numeric>
using namespace std;

int main(){
  vector<double> score(10);

  for(vector<double>::size_type i=0;i<20;i++) {
    cout<<"Enter marks for student #"<<i+1<<":"<<flush;
    cin>>score[i];
  }

  double total = accumulate(score.begin(), score.end(),0);

  cout<<"Total score:"<<total<<endl<<"Average score:"<<total/score.size()<<flush;

  return 0;
}
```

In the `for` sentence in line #9, I am declaring `i` as a **`vector<double>::size_type`** type (because I was told to do so).
I tested the code with the type said above replaced with an **`int`**, and it worked perfectly fine.
Why is **`vector<double>::size_type`** preferred compared to **`int`**?

Comment: Your current code goes out of bounds of the vector. If you change 20 to `score.size()`, you should get a warning about signed and unsigned comparison. By the way, your call to `flush` is not necessary as the output is flushed before input is read.

Comment: I always use `std::size_t`. I *think* it's permissible. If not then I have an afternoon of refactoring to do!

Comment: @Bathsheba, All implementations I know of make `std::size_t` the type. There's probably one that doesn't, of course.

Comment: @chris I think it is there because an allocator can change the type of the container's `size_type`. There's a non-negligible probability that I just dreamt that up though.

Comment: Sorry guys, 20 is my mistake, it's 10. I don't know why I did that

Comment: Because `vector<T>::size_type` may not be the same type on all platforms. BTW, on most platforms, it's `size_t` (not `int`), but that's not necessarily true on **all** platforms.

Comment: @coffeeFlow No mistake. Everything's fine.

Comment: @juanchopanza, Now that I think of it, I believe it is usually defined in terms of the allocator.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

`size_type` is guaranteed to be large enough for the largest supported vector size, `vector::max_size()`. `int` is not: on many common platforms, `int` has 32 bits, while `max_size()` is considerably larger than 2<sup>31</sup>.

If you know the size is (and will always be) a small number like 20, then you can get away with using `int` or any other integer type instead of `size_type`. If you were to change the program, for example to read the size from the input, then it would go horribly wrong if that value were larger than `INT_MAX`; while using `size_type`, it would continue working for any value up to `max_size()`, which you can easily test for.

Comment: Is there any specific reason to not use `std::size_t`, i.e., any specific situation where `size_type` of `std::vector` is not just an alias of `std::size_t`? I always use `std::size_t` for array/vector/whatever indexing and size representation, since its supposed to be the standard/portable type for that purposes.

Comment: @Manu343726: The standards does not guarantee that the `size_type` will be `std::size_t`. But in practice, it is always. So whether to use `std::size_t` or `size_type` depends on how "pure" you want to be in terms of standard compliance. Personally I find `std::vector<double>::size_type` to be too long.

Comment: It actually is long but isn't that what typedef and C++11 'type aliasing' are meant to simplify? Using it is actually free :)

Answer (score 7):

The embedded type `vector<double>::size_type` relates to the return value for various `vector` methods, such as `.size()`, hence the preference in that case to use matching types (the `int = 0` would generally result in a sign mismatch warning). E.g.

```
for (vector<double>::size_type i = 0; i < score.size(); ++i) { // types match
  // ...
}

for (int i = 0; i < score.size(); ++i) { // types mismatch
  // ...
}
```

`std::vector::size_type` is required to be large enough to represent the maximum number of elements that could be contained in a container, in this case `vector<double>::max_size()`. In general, it maps to `size_t`.

In your case, there is no explicit reason to use the `vector<double>::size_type` (although it would technically be better to use `size_type`) since the loop runs from 0 to 20 and both are `int`. Hence the following would be ok.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 20; ++i) { // loops 20 times
  // ...
}
```

Additional notes:

Favour iterator based loops over index based ones:

```
for (vector<double>::iterator i = score.begin(); i != score.end(); ++i) {
  // ...
}
```

It wasn't tagged as C++11, but if that is possible, the range based for loops deals with a lot of this.

```
for (double& i : score) {
  // ...
}
```

Or even using a `for_each` with a lambda.

Answer (score 4):

The `vector` `size_type` is what's used by vector to do size comparisons.  If you had a loop that used an `int` as a counter and compared against the vector's actual size, you'd get warnings from the compiler about signed vs. unsigned integer comparisons:

```
for( int i=0; i<score.size(); i++ ){  // <-- signed vs. unsigned comparisons
    // do something...
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Your problem is two fold.

First, you are writing beyond the end of the `std::vector` -- the `std::vector` has 10 elements, and you are writing to 20.

In order to fix this, and to follow the Don't Repeat Yourself principle, you'd change your code as follows:

```
int main(){
  std::vector<double> score(20);

  for(std::vector<double>::size_type i=0;i<score.size();i++) {
```

where I both made the `vector` larger and used its size to determine how much to write.

Now, when we try to replace that long clause with `int`:

```
int main(){
  std::vector<double> score(20);

  for(int i=0;i<score.size();i++) {
```

we get a singed/unsigned comparison (probably):

```
i<score.size()
```

where `score.size()` is an unsigned value of type `std::vector<double>::size_type`, and `i` is an `int`.

Compilers often give warnings in these cases, as it is really easy to get nonsensical results (if `i` < `0`, the comparison will usually result in the negative number comparing larger than the positive one!)  In addition, if the size of the `vector` is larger than the max value of `int` (on some systems, as small as `32767`, usually at least `2147483647`, and sometimes much larger -- this is a value the compiler is reasonably free to pick for itself, the C++ standard does not specify it fully), the loop will fail spectacularly.

Now, while the type of `std::vector<double>::size()` is `std::vector<double>::size_type`, this is (in every implementation I've experienced) just `std::size_t`.  So that is a shorter way to say it:

```
  for(std::size_t i=0;i<score.size();i++) {
```

(`std::size_t` is defined in `<cstddef>` as an aside).

If you are programming in C++11, you can do one better:

```
int i=0;
for(double& student:score) {
  std::cout<<"Enter marks for student #"<<++i<<":"<<std::flush;
  std::cin>>student;
}
```

which is a range-based `for` loop and avoid the problem of indexing entirely.

Comment: Something is wrong with the body of your ranged-for's body.

Comment: @quentin it just needed more breathing space

Comment: Hey, it does look better now. But won't compile for lack of a declared `i` ;)