# What is meaning of these C++ statements typedef vector<double>::size_type

Tags: c++, vector

I am beginner in C++ and have question about these statements.

```
vector<double> vec1;
typedef vector<double>::size_type vec_size
vec_size size = vec1.size()
```

From question, 
[C++: "vector<int>::size_type variable" - what is the point of declaring in this way?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24825712/c-vectorintsize-type-variable-what-is-the-point-of-declaring-in-this?noredirect=1), I understand that `size::type` holds largest possible vector size. I am confused what *type* is `size::type` - is it a function, variable, etc.?

Using [typedef](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Typedef)  `vec_size` is equivalent to `vector<double>::size_type`. So the third line becomes

```
vector<double>::size_type size = vec1.size()
```

This is very confusing to me. What is *type* of variable `size`?

It would be really helpful if someone comments in simplified language.

Comment: `size_type` is an unsigned integral type. The whole point of providing that typedef is so you don't have to know what exact type your implementation uses. That being said, it most likely is `size_t`.

Comment: adding to what Praetorian said, Containers::size_type. All containers have the size_type which correlates to size_t. It's not just vector. It comes in handy when dealing with algorithms and sorting. Check out Effective STL , pretty good book

Answer (score 3):

The are really two questions here:

> what is the point of declaring in this way

It's to keep your fingers from falling off your hand. If you need to reference this type over and over again, it's easier to just type `vec_size` each time, instead of spelling out `vector<double>::size_type`. Each. and. every. time.

Use the `typedef`. Your fingers will thank you for it. Especially the little pinky finger, who doesn't have to hit the <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> key so often, any more.

Not to mention that it makes the resulting code easier on the eyes, too.

Now, as far as the second question:

> What is type of variable size?

The answer is: you don't know, and you shouldn't care. The only thing you should care about is that this type is sufficient to represent the number of elements in the vector. That's the definition of what this type is.

It might be an `unsigned int`, or an `unsigned long`, or even an `unsigned long long`. But don't worry about it. Whatever it is, it will be big enough to express the size of the largest possible vector you have even the slightest hope of declaring and using. This also means that this type would also be the right type for representing an index of any element in the vector. So, if you need to save the index of some particular element in the vector, or iterate over the values in the vector by their index, this is the right type for it. Since it's big enough to represent the size of the vector, it's big enough to represent the index of any particular value in the vector.

Of course, for vectors whose size is expected to be quite modest, by today's standards, using a plain `int` will also work. But by using this type, you'll be bragging to all your friends: see, I know a lot about C++. I know how to use this type properly.

Answer (score 1):

> This is very confusing to me. What is *type* of variable `size`?

Your question answers itself: it is a variable of type `vector<double>::size_type`. Consider the following:

```
struct type_name
{
  typedef int inner;
};
```

What is `type_name::inner`? It's a `typedef` stored within the type `type_name`. The `::` there is the C++ scope syntax; it's used to refer to names which are declared within other names. Here, we declare `inner` within the type `type_name`. So its full name is `type_name::inner`.

In all other respects, it is no different from any other `typedef`.

`std::vector` is defined to have a type alias declared within it called `size_type`. Exactly what type is it an alias of? That's not stated by the standard.

What *is* stated is the meaning of this type. It is an unsigned integer type which is big enough to be able to index any element in the largest possible `vector`. `at` and `operator[]` take values of `size_type`; `size` and `capacity` take values of `size_type`. Indeed, any member of `vector` that relates in any way to its size or indexes elements takes a value of `size_type` type.

Though odds are good it's going to be a `typedef` of `size_t`.

Answer (score 0):

The type of `vec_size` is `std::vector<double>::size_type`.   This will often be a `typedef` for some unsigned integral type, but the actual type is implementation defined.

In other words, it varies between compilers and their shipped standard library (and header files).

It will often be a `std::size_t` (or something equivalent to it) but is allowed to be something different.   The actual type of `std::size_t` is also implementation-defined - it might be `unsigned`, `unsigned long`, `unsigned long long`, `uint32_t`, `uint_64_t`.   It might be something else (e.g. some class type that provides required operations).

If you want to work with sizes using some "simpler" type (say, `unsigned long`) then you can.   But then you accept the risk that your chosen type does not support all possible sizes of the vector - which can mean bugs in your program that are hard to track down.    Using `std::vector<double>::size_type` is guaranteed to work with all compilers and standard libraries that correctly conform with the standard.